# Group Android notifications in Firebase Cloud Messaging using Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have a Cloud Function that send notifications to iOS/Android devices through Firebase Cloud Messaging.

We can group notifications for iOS devices by specifying **thread-id** in the FCM notification payload. How could I do the same for Android devices?

As per link below we can use .setGroup(**GROUP_KEY**) in Java/Kotlin for FCM but there is not an option/field for the notification payload to specify a group in the FCM HTTP API.

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group